# How could I vertically align the input fields?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/km82xwto/1/

```
input
{
    vertical-align: top;
    /*   Not working */
}
```

I want to put the submit button right under the input fields. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you clearly state what you want exactly?

Comment: I wanna put the submit button right under the last input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated :

```
[type="submit"] {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 140px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I've tried vertical-align: top; line-height: 1.5;. Still doesn't work. It is not the case.

Comment: Is there another way to do it without using fixed pixel?

Comment: you can give margin in %

Comment: Adding space in front is one solution. Is there a better way to do it? I'm thinking vertical align. Just can't make it work

Comment: vertical align wont work. You can better use tables instead of all the paddings and stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to change the html.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following css:

```
#form{
 width:500px;/*adjust later*/
}
input[type=submit]{
 float:right;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-top:10px;/*adjust later*/
 margin-right:10px; /*adjust later*/
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do it? Adding space in front is one solution, but I am looking for vertical aligning solution.

Comment: Vertically align should be done via adding margin-top.